# sorting an existing array with PHP

Tags: php, sorting

At the moment, I'm pulling in data from an MySQL database using PDO. At one point in the page I have

```
<?php
  $sitelinks=$pdo->query("SELECT * FROM sitelinks WHERE `show` = 'yes' ORDER BY `Order` ASC")
             ->fetchAll();

foreach ($sitelinks as $sitelink) {
    echo "\n<li class=\"linkitem\"><a href=\"{$sitelink['URL']}\">{$links['Text']}</a></li>";
}
?>
```

and then later on in the page I'm using the `$sitelink` values again like so:

```
<?php
foreach ($sitelinks as $sitelink) {
    echo '\n<li class=\"desktoplinkitem\">
                <a href=\"{$sitelink['URL']}\">{$sitelink['Text']}</a>
            </li>";
}
?>
```

In the first block I'm getting the `$sitelink` elements in the correct order (as they are being sorted in the MySQL query by the values in the `Order` column)

What I want to do is then sort the second block, also by this same `Order` column. From looking at the PHP manual I'm guessing an `array_multisort` would probably be best, but I'm a little confused as to the correct syntax. I tried the following:

```
<?php
    foreach ($sitelinks as $sitelink) {
        array_multisort($sitelink[`Order`], SORT_ASC);
        echo    "\n<li class=\"desktoplinkitem\">
        <a href=\"{$sitelink['URL']}\">{$sitelink['Text']}</a></li>";
    }
?>
```

EDIT: apologies, I've totally confused myself here - the order *ISN'T* changing, it's processing the correct way. My confusion came from the fact that I am then floating the `li` elements with `float: right` in the second block, which makes the links appear in reverse.

What I actually want to do is sort the second block descending by `Order` so that the second block reads 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 instead of 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 as it does now.

Comment: Do you mean that your array is changes after first foreach loop...is it so?

Comment: Surely you want to sort it ___before___ your `foreach` loop

Comment: I think you can use php sort() function for the second block.

Comment: @Ali - the array is exactly the same both times, no changed. But when I'm `echo`ing it, it displays in the correct order in the first block, but then the wrong order in the second block. 

@Mark - I did also try `<?php
            array_multisort($sitelink[`Order`], SORT_ASC);
      foreach ($sitelinks as $sitelink) {
      echo "\n<li class=\"desktoplinkitem\"><a href=\"{$sitelink['URL']}\">{$sitelink['Text']}</a></li>";
      }
     ?>` but no joy.

Comment: Sort the array and then process across it with the foreach

Comment: ___What I want to do is then sort the second block, also by this same Order column___ Does not make sense. If you want it sorted in the same way, you dont have to do anything to it. **Its already sorted on order** Unless you have done something to change the order between the first use and the second use!

Comment: Can you show more of your code? If you don't change the array, the array does not change its order by itself.

Comment: Why are you using `{$links['Text']}` in the first foreach and `{$sitelink['Text']}` in the second?

Comment: @qooplmao - nice spot, thats from an earlier version of the code.

Comment: Yes, I think @YourCommonSense avatar sums this up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at using `array_reverse`

```
$reversed = array_reverse($sitelinks);

foreach ($reversed as $sitelink) {
    echo    "\n<li class=\"desktoplinkitem\"><a href=\"{$sitelink['URL']}\">{$sitelink['Text']}</a></li>";
}
```

Comment: Once we understand the issue, the answer is simple. Good luck, or should that be 'see you soon`

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case, I suggest to use **array_reverse**

It will basically returns the same array but in inverse order. This way is much easier and clear that your using the same order criteria, just changing asc for desc.

```
<?php
$siteLinkDesc = array_reverse($siteLinkDesc);
?>
```

Hope this helps.
In case you'd still' like to go for the multisort way. It's more complex, and I only recommend using if the order criteria is different than the original. This is what you should do (sort of):
1. Get an array of your sorting criteria:
    foreach ($sitelinks $key => $sitelink) {
         $orderSorting[$key] = $sitelink['Order'];
    }

2. Apply multi-sorting to original array:

   array_multisort($orderSorting, SORT_DESC, $sitelinks);